# excel Find multiple conditional results

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

I am looking into doing som statistics on users task stati.

Data Sheet1:

```
    A   B   C   D
1   NAMEID  NAME    TASK    STATUS
2   1002    Lars    Sorting Done
3   1003    Erik    Sorting Done
4   1002    Lars    Stacking    Awaiting
5   1004    Brian   Sorting Awaiting
```

Helper Stati Sheet2:
A list of the available Stati with an numerical id attached

```
    A   B
1   STATUS  STATUSID
2   Startup 11
3   Awaiting    22
4   Done    33
```

Stat Sheet3:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
1   NAMEID  NAME    Startup Awaiting    Done
2   1002    Lars    0   1   1
3   1003    Erik    0   0   1
4   1004    Brian   0   1   0
```

I need to find, per Stat:NAMEID, if there is more than 0(zero) stati in the data list equal to Helper:STATUS - if present, print 1, if not present, print 0.

anyone?

Comment: On sheet 2 you have numerical value for each task, but you don't use it anywhere else? Is this not just a sumifs()?

Comment: When I get back from lunch I can test it on my computer but it seems you only need one function as mentioned above

Comment: I don't see why you need `Sheet2` apart from a simple list of knowing what to count. But that list is in your first row on `Sheet3`. So it seems like you just want to get a count of `Sheet1`, correct?

Comment: That's how I see it too...

Comment: Sheet2 is only as a simple list of knowing what to count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are Danish so because of that I will give you the Danish functions and comment with the English.

```
' In sheet 3 C2: 
  =TÆL.HVISER(Sheet1!A:A;A2;Sheet1!D:D;$C$1) ' =countifs(Sheet1!A:A;A2;Sheet1!D:D;$C$1)

' in sheet 3 D2:
  =TÆL.HVISER(Sheet1!A:A;A2;Sheet1!D:D;$D$1) ' =countifs(Sheet1!A:A;A2;Sheet1!D:D;$D$1)

' in sheet 3 E2:
  =TÆL.HVISER(Sheet1!A:A;A2;Sheet1!D:D;$E$1) ' =countifs(Sheet1!A:A;A2;Sheet1!D:D;$E$1)
```

and fill down to suit.

I placed it all on one sheet but it will work on multiple sheets too.
[image]

EDIT: forgot to add sheet in the formula

Answer (score 1):

Here is a formula that should work for you:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$5,Sheet3!$A2,Sheet1!$D$2:$D$5,Sheet3!C$1)
```

Put it in cell `C2`. Then drag down and across.